# How to access Request body in FastAPI class based view

Tags: python, fastapi

I have the `request` object as class-level dependency like shown [here](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/), to be able to use it in all routes within the class. The problem however is when I try to access the request body - it errors with `Stream consumed` error.

Example code:

```
from fastapi import File, Request, UploadFile
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv


app = FastAPI()
router = InferringRouter()

@cbv(router)
class ExampleRouteClass:
    request: Request
    file: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)
    type: Optional[str] = None
    
     @router.post("/example-route/")
     async def example_function(self):
         headers = self.request.headers # this works like a charm
         data = await self.request.json() # this errors with RuntimeError: Stream consumed
         return headers

app.include_router(router)
```

Example `curl` request:

```
curl -x POST 'http://example.com:port/example-route'
-H 'secret-key: supersecret'
-d '{"some_data": "data"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `UploadFile` - so as a solution I placed it in the route itself, as it is the only route in the class that uses it anyway.

Leaving this here for anyone who has this error:

```
class ExampleRouteClass:
    request: Request
    type: Optional[str] = None
    
     @router.post("/example-route/")
     async def example_function(self, file: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)):
         headers = self.request.headers # this works like a charm
         data = await self.request.json() # this works now too
         return headers
```